# Hangfire configuration for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, configuration, asp.net-mvc-5, app-startup, hangfire

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and am wishing to use `Hangfire` for recurring tasks.

How can I setup `Hangfire` to use `SQL Server storage` without specifying this in the `Startup.Auth` `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` function.

Here is a resource link for SQL Server configuration: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html

This resource states that:

> If you want to use Hangfire outside of web application, where OWIN
>   Startup class is not applicable, create an instance of the
>   SqlServerStorage manually and pass it to the JobStorage.Current static
>   property. Parameters are the same.

The example code is as follows:

```
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connection string or its name");
```

I have tried the following code (with my own connection string), yet the dashboard is not available. I have called the code above from a controller function.

Is there something that I have not done correct? How can I setup `Hangfire` to use `SQL Server storage` without using the `Startup.Auth` class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, it would help if you specify *why* you can't or don't want to use OWIN for this.  You say "I am coding a MVC 5 internet application" yet you quote a source regarding "If you want to use Hangfire outside of web application" - So which is it?  You mention not wanting to use `Startup.Auth` but normally this type of thing would go in a plain `Startup` separate from any auth stuff anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem:

> I have called the code above from a controller function.

You should be setting this up once on application startup - either in the `Configuration` method of an OWIN `Startup` class (followed by an `app.UseHangFireServer();`), or in the `Application_Start` method of your `Global.asax.cs` if you really don't want to use OWIN. Either way, the line you're looking for is right there in the documentation you reference:

```
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(@"connection string or connection string name");
```

HOWEVER, as far as I know, if you want to use the dashboard you *must* configure that part via OWIN along with an authorization filter.  See http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html

So really, I don't know if any downside of using the OWIN configuration for all of this.  It's the more modern platform, and since you mention this is for an MVC5 app it's unlikely that you have legacy concerns.